# How to make generic function that return int or date or string

Tags: c#, generics, expression, expression-trees

I need to realize a function which return an `Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>`, where T could be an integer, a string or a datetime.
The caller won't know the type of T.
What I want to achieve is a function which create a predicate that can be used in a Linq OrderBy function.
The should be something like:

```
class FilterCreator {
   ...
   Expression<Func<MyObject, T>> getOrderExpression()
   {
   ...
   }
}

class Consumer{
   void mymethod()
   {
      var orderedList = MyList.OrderBy(filterCreator.getOrderExpression());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics don't work that way.  You would have to either make the caller know the type of T or replace T with Object.

Comment: The allowable range of types for T is part of the interface, and must be made as public as the interface.

Comment: Ok, but I still need a method to generate an order predicate dinamically. If there's another way, any suggestion is welcome. Mine was just an example, knowing that it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: How is getOrderExpression supposed to know what to order by?